# Eclipse: open in browser rather than code pane

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-adt

Mousing over an Android class I get a popup tool tip.

One of the links opens up the documentation for the class. However it currently opens this up in the code pane and I'd like it to open up in a browser.

How do you change this behaviour?

Comment: I am not aware of any option to do this. There is a separate JavaDoc view you can open (`Window > Show View > Javadoc`).

Answer (score 0):

Put caret on the class name in Java Editor and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.